# Performance problems with net.tcp binding using WAS in IIS

Tags: wcf, net.tcp

We are facing problems with our net.tcp services hosted in IIS even under minimal load. The same services are also exposed through HTTPS from another endpoint. Clients using HTTPS work without any issues.

Environment details:
Windows 7 SP1, 64 bit, x64
.Net Framework 4.0 with Update

We have already installed the hotfix available from here http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=35626

We have tried our service with both port sharing enabled and disabled and with security turned off for net.tcp binding.

The services die down even under moderate load. If however, we send single requests, the service continues to work.

Any pointers on web.config or SmSvcHost.exe.config to make the services stable will be very helpful.

```
<binding closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
        sendTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered"
        transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferPoolSize="8388608" maxBufferSize="1048576" maxConnections="50"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="1048576">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="1048576"
        maxArrayLength="1048576" maxBytesPerRead="1048576" maxNameTableCharCount="1048576" />
    <security mode="Transport">
        <transport protectionLevel="None" />
    </security>
</binding>
```

Comment: Have you specified any service throttling settings? such as MaxConcurrentCalls/maxConcurrentSessions? If so, please post it in your question.

Comment: No, we've not specified any throttling settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hotfix seems to have fixed the problem. It seems that it was not correctly installed. Reinstalling it fixed the problem.